# Dockerimage working on pull but not on pull image directive in yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have a dockerimage on a gitlab registry.
when I (after login on a target machine)

`docker run -d -p 8081:8080/tcp gitlab.somedomain.com:5050/root/app`

the laravel app is available and running and reachable. Things like `php artisan config:clear` are working. when I enter the container everything looks fine.
But I don't have any services running. So I had the idea to create a yml file to `docker-compose run` to set things up in `docker-compose-gitlab.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: my-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
      - MYSQL_USER=username
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  application:
    image: gitlab.somedomain.com:5050/root/app:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: my-app
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/application
    env_file: .env.docker
    working_dir: /application
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
```

calling `docker-compose --verbose -f docker-compose-gitlab.yml up` shows me that the mysql service is created and working, the app seems also be creeated but then fails ... exiting with code 0 - no further message.

If I add commands in my yml like `php artisan config:clear` the error gets even unclearer for me: it says it cannot find `artisan` and it seems as if the command is executed outside the container ... exiting with code 1. (artisan is a helper and executed via php)

When I call the docker-compose with `-d` and then do `docker ps` I can only see mysql running but not the app.

When I use both strategies, the problem is, the two container do not share a common network and can so not work together.

What did I miss? Is this the wrong strategy?

Comment: From inside `my-app` container how do you try to connect to `my-mysql` in these 2 different strategies? Two gotchas here are **(1)** there is no communication between different networks (`default bridge` automatically used by `docker run ...` / `user-defined` bridge automatically created by `docker-compose up`) and **(2)** wrong usage of `localhost:[your_published_port]`)

Comment: @tgogos can you clarify your question? I am not sure what you're meaning. The whole setup of the basic yml configuration worked fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that I let a volume directive left over which overwrites my entier application with an empty directory.

You can just leave that out.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: my-mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
      - MYSQL_USER=username
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  application:
    image: gitlab.somedomain.com:5050/root/app:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: my-app
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
##    volumes:
##      - .:/application ## this would overwrite the app
    env_file: .env.docker
    working_dir: /application
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    links:
      - mysql
```

Answer (score -1):

You can debug the network of the containers listing the networks with `docker network ls`
then when the list is shown inspect the compose network with `docker inspect <ComposeNetworkID>`
Once you are shure that your services are not in the same network, remove your containers and recreate it again with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-gitlab.yml up`

If you notice they are in the same network try to use the container name instead localhost to reach each other, if it is the case.

Comment: The are not created at once with this command. That's the main problem. So they won't ever be in the same network as long I use two calls to create two containers, right? Please read my problem again :)